# Adding images as arrays into a larger array using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create an array of images using Numpy to feed it into an image classification neural network. When I put the image into an array, it comes 3 dimensions,but when I use np.append to append it into my array of all of the images the shape is 631800003. Why is this happening and how do I fix this? Or should I be loading the images some other way?

Here is my code for the variable definition cell:

```py
normal = np.array([])
normalSet = np.array([])
badSet = np.array([])

Labels = np.array([])
Training_data = np.array([])
validationSet = []

process_data = True
ramCheck = 0
```

And the image loading:

```py
if process_data:

    for image in os.listdir('train/NORMAL/'):

        normal = imread('train/NORMAL/'+image)        
        normalSet = np.append(normal, normalSet)
        Labels = np.append(Labels, 0)

        validationSet.append(normal)

    for image in os.listdir('train/PNEUMONIA/'):

        bad = imread('train/PNEUMONIA/'+image)
        badSet = np.append(badSet, bad)
        Labels = np.append(Labels, 1)

        validationSet.append(bad)

    print("done!")

    Training_Data = np.append(badSet, normalSet)

    np.save("TrainingData.npy", Training_data)
    np.save("TrainingLabels.npy", Labels)

else:
    Training_data = np.load("TrainingData.npy")
    Labels = np.load("TrainingLabels.npy")
```

Comment: You did not read the `np.append` docs (or at least not carefully).  Without an axis paraemter, it flattens all inputs, producing a 1d array.  But in general it is not a good idea to `np.append` or `np.concatenate` iteratively.  Get a list of arrays, and join them with one call to `np.array` or one of the `concatenate` family.  And make sure your images all have the same shape.

Comment: It's also a good idea to test functions like `np.append` with small examples in an interactive session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append into a list easier than change the list to a numpy array which will have the correct dimensions you need to feed it to a neural network.

```
normalSet = []
labels = []

for image in os.listdir('train/NORMAL/'):

    normal = imread('train/NORMAL/'+ image)

    normalSet.append(normal)
    validationSet.append(normal)
    labels.append(0)

normalSet = np.array(normalSet)
labels = np.array(labels)
```

Comment: So I do that but when I append the 2 arrays together it comes as (234, 900, 1000, 6) instad of (468, 900, 1000, 3) because there are 468 images.

Comment: Oh I just had to reshape

Comment: Append them together as a list first before changing them into a numpy array will get the job done for you.